# Color from the WPF ColorPicker to a Rectangle brush?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, colors, brush

I have a `Rectangle` property and the `ColorPicker` from the `Extended WPF Toolkit` in my `colorprotype.xaml`

```
<Rectangle Name="rect_NewSelect" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource ColorInfoRectangle}" Width="60"/>
```

And

```
<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="ClrPcker_Background" Margin="-36,-389,2,411" RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,0.4" SelectedColor="Transparent" MouseDown="ColorPickerColor_MouseDown" DisplayColorAndName="True"   Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

So I placed the "MouseDown" event in my `colorprotype.xaml.cs` of the ColorPicker to be able to put the selected color from the Picker in the rectangle.

```
private void ColorPickerColor_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rect_NewSelect == null) return;
        rect_NewSelect.Fill = ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor;

    }
```

But after putting this, an error occurs and tells me:

> Unable to convert System.Windows.Media.Color type to System.Windows.Media.Brush.

So, How can I convert "Color" to "Brush"? What is the monumental error in my code?

> Knowing that: my project is coded in C # with .NET 4.6.1.
>   [image]

From the image: ColorPicker = Red combobox and Rectangle = Blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `SelectedColorChange` event of the `ColorPicker` like this:

```
<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="ClrPcker_Background" Margin="-36,-389,2,411"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.476,0.4" SelectedColor="Transparent"
                  SelectedColorChanged="ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged" DisplayColorAndName="True" 
                  Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

---

```
private void ClrPcker_Background_SelectedColorChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Color?> e)
{
    if (rect_NewSelect == null || ClrPcker_Background == null || !ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.HasValue)
        return;

    rect_NewSelect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor.Value);
}
```

You should access the `Value` property of the `SelectedColor` property to get the actual `Color` object that was selected.

Comment: You are the savior of all my problems! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new brush from that picked color. SolidColorBrush class has constructor that accepts Color type.

```
rect_NewSelect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor);
```

Comment: Returns the error "Conversion impossible from" System.Windows.Media.Color? "to" System.Windows.Media.Color "

Comment: Then try rect_NewSelect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ClrPcker_Background.SelectedColor);

Comment: This time it works but the rectangle does not display the color